# java on Linux arm64 downloads x86 libraries by mistake

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, shared-libraries, arm64

I have a java 7 application that requires gtk libraries.  I have installed those available on Ubuntu 18.04.  However these don't seem to be compatible.

I have noticed that there is what appears to be a temp java library download folder:

```
~/.swt/lib/linux/aarch64
```

Where the application or java engine keeps downloading missing library dependencies for instance:

```
libswt-gtk-4234.so
```

But a file of these reveals it is a x86 library!!!

```
libswt-gtk-4234.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

I was wondering if this can be controlled and I can make java download the aarch64 libraries instead.

I have tried linking all the libraries in :

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/aarch64
```

But these libraries have different version numbers

```
libswt-gtk-4919.so instead of libswt-gtk-4234.so
```

and the x86 will end up downloading anyway.

I have tried manually linking libswt-gtk-4919.so to libswt-gtk-4234.so but the java application faults with UnsatisfiedLinkError: type errors.

I need to figure out how to make the java download the correct architecture libraries or find the correct libraries myself to place there.

I believe these libraries are part of eclipse (but not sure).

Comment: This is the Eclipse SWT GUI library, there is no build of SWT for AArch64

Comment: The only versions you'll find were built by Linux distributions, and installed through their own package management systems. Unless something has changed, Ubuntu has a very old, outdated, version, but it is there.

Comment: @ nitind : I believe I have those libraries installed and they are enough to get the application running when I set an option on the application to use a lite UI but it fails on the full UI.  So I suspect the libraries are not fully compatible.